# jQuery: Animating width/height, but Stay Centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have an element on the page that I've already centered horizontally and vertically (It's a jQuery UI Modal Dialog), and want to resize it using .animate() like this:

```
<div id="element" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Hi Stack Overflow!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#element').animate({ height: "200px" });
</script>
```

That works fine, except the element only grows downwards. What I'm trying to do is have the element grow vertically in both directions (in this case 50px in each direction) so it stays centered. Is there a way that it can be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9Js/3/)***

```
var growEl = $("#grow"),
    curHeight = $("#grow").height(),
    curTop = growEl.offset().top,
    newHeight = 200,
    newMargin = curTop -(newHeight -curHeight)/2;

if(newMargin < 0){
 newMargin = 0;   
}

$("#grow").animate({height:newHeight+"px", marginTop:newMargin + 'px'});
```

**Formula for figuring out what to make the margin**

```
NewTopMargin = CurrentMargin-(NewHeight-OldHeight)/2
```

Thanks @bobsoap for reminding me to use offset.top

Comment: That's what I tried at first, but I discovered a flaw. The new top margin may be a negative number if the browser window is small. In that case, the element should grow up as much as it can (with a margin), and down the rest of the way. I was hoping there wouldn't be a lot math or complicated animation calculations. I want to keep this thing speedy.

Comment: @mellowsoon you can get the position of the element with `offset`, then access it with `offset.top`. You can't get around doing some math, but it's not a "complicated animation calculation" anyway. You first do some basic math, which JS is fast at, then you do a single animate() function, which you're doing already.

Comment: Updated again, to use offset().top.

Comment: Awesome answer, how can we get the text vertically aligned center the whole time, while the box expands?

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-top: -50px, height: 50px;
```

That sort of thing (sorry its not code formatted) i'm sure you can insert it correctly.